# Make subfolder names from part of file name and copy files with Robocopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

Is it posible to copy and make directories automatically from file name substrings using Robocopy?

I mean i have files like these. `LAJ00306130201004626.rc` the **first 8 chararacters** are *control number* (`LAJ00306`=control number) this would be the name of the folder and the rest are the date and time (Date=130201) (time=004626).

```
LAJ00306130201004626.rc
LAJ00306130202004626.rc
LAJ00306130203004626.rc
LAJ00307130201004626.rc
LAJ00307130202004626.rc
```

and i would like to copy and create folders from the file name like under and copy the files mentioned before in the new folders.

```
LAJ00306
LAJ00307
```

I hope to be clear if necessary ask me for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\source folder"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.rc) do (
    set "name=%%a"
    robocopy "%cd%" "%%a" "D:\target directory\!name:~0,8!" 
)
popd
```

Answers to your questions are:

`pushd "drive:\path"` makes the location the current working directory.
`popd` restores the last working directory
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` allows you to change and use variables within a loop, using the !variable! syntax.

If your 2000 files are in a single folder then it should work - but test it on some sample files first so that you can see how it will work.

Comment: thanks foxidrive could you explain me what are pushd, popd  and enabledelayedexpansion for. They are more than 2000 files i have to copy every day this would work in whit this condition, regards

Comment: Thanks Foxidrive this really works thanks you very much. This site really rocks. see you Foxidrive

Answer (score 2):

try this, look at the output and remove the `echo`s before `MD` and `ROBOCOPY`, if it looks good:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcefolder=."
SET "targetfolder=X:\data"

CD /d "%sourcefolder%"
FOR %%a IN (*.rc) DO (
    SET "fname=%%a"
    SET "folder=!fname:~0,8!"
    SET "$!folder!=1"
)

FOR /f "delims=$=" %%a IN ('set "$"') DO (
    ECHO MD "%targetfolder%\%%a" 2>nul
    ECHO ROBOCOPY "%sourcefolder%" "%targetfolder%\%%a" "%%a*.rc"
)
```

Set `sourcefolder` and `targetfolder` for your folder tree.

Comment: Endoro thanks for responding i just proved your code but it doesn´t work, i don´t know much about batch script synsax and so on, i just changed the path for sourcefolder and targer folder, if you could explain me how this code works. Mainly this "$!folder!=1" why ! !, excuse me my low knowledge,

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%i IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*."'
) DO XCOPY /b "%sourcedir%\%%i_%%j" "%destdir%\%%i\"
GOTO :EOF
```

This should accomplish the task described. You'd need to set up the source and destination directories to suit, of course. Add `>nul` to the end of the `XCOPY` line to suppress 'copied' messages.

Comment: Hello Peter thanks for responding. I just update my issue to be more clear i hope you can help us. The issue here is that i have to use Robocopy your procedure could be used with Robocopy? Regards